# Can my Arborvitae be saved after a fire?

Tags: trees

I recently had a brush fire which burned my Arborvitae hedge in several places. Can these plants be saved? They are mature and at least 20 years old.

[image: Arborvitae after fire.]

Comment: Very difficult to answer this without a picture. Can you post some?  Just edit your answer

Comment: Evergreen trees are more susceptible to permanent damage than deciduous. As a rough rule of thumb, if less that 10% of an evergreen tree is stlll green, it will not survive. But even if it does survive, the "structural damage" will be permanent - it won't regrow damaged parts.

Comment: @alephzero deciduous, learned a new word today.  And I did not know that about evergreens.  Good response.